# How to save a screenshot as pdf in C# (Forms)?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, pdf, printing

How can i take a screenshot of my windows forms programm and save in pdf ???

ive tried this code: The output is a white page

```
            // generate a file name as the current date/time in unix timestamp format
            string file = (string)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds.ToString();

            // the directory to store the output.
            string directory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

            PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument()
            {
                PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings()
                {
                    // set the printer to 'Microsoft Print to PDF'
                    PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF",

                    // tell the object this document will print to file
                    PrintToFile = true,

                    // set the filename to whatever you like (full path)
                    PrintFileName = Path.Combine(directory, file + ".pdf"),
                }
            };
            doc.PrintPage+= new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintImage);
            CaptureScreen();
            doc.Print();
```

Comment: Because you're not actually saving anything? You'll need to save your screen capture to a file (.jpg, gif etc) and then print that file

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. (using iTextSharp)
Here is my code:

```
            Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
            bmp = new Bitmap(this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height + 10, g);
            Graphics mg = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            mg.CopyFromScreen(this.Location.X + 20, this.Location.Y + 25 ,40, 47, this.Size);
            // Save the screenshot to the specified path that the user has chosen.
            bmp.Save("Screenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);


            Document document = new Document();
            document.SetMargins(1,1,1,1);


            using (var stream = new FileStream("test.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
                document.Open();
                using (var imageStream = new FileStream("Screenshot.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    var image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageStream);                       
                    float maxWidth = document.PageSize.Width - document.LeftMargin - document.RightMargin;
                    float maxHeight = document.PageSize.Height - document.TopMargin - document.BottomMargin;
                    if (image.Height > maxHeight || image.Width > maxWidth)
                        image.ScaleToFit(maxWidth, maxHeight);
                    document.Add(image);
                }
                document.Close();
            }
```

Comment: if we have multiple pages form, can you guide me for that, it is only working for one page

Comment: This code does not compile. PdfWriter does not have a definition for GetInstance